# How to make sure that first case details are entered before moving on to second case in c#

Tags: c#

e.g., a c# program that asks user to enter their personal details in case "1" and usage details in case "2". But make sure that the personal details are entered. I am done with the program but facing problems with making sure that the personal details are entered before it executes case"2".

```
    case"1":
    Console.Write("Name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine(); //input name
                while (name.Length == 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be empty");
                    Console.Write("Full Name: ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();

                }
    break;
    case"2":
    Console.Write("Emails: \n" + "0     5     25     50     100     250+ \n");
                    while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Email) == false || Email != 0 && Email != 5 && Email != 25 && Email != 50 && Email != 100 && Email != 250) 
                    { Console.WriteLine("Cannot be empty"); Console.Write("Emails: \n" + "0     5     25     50     100     250+ \n"); }
                    EmailDataUsage = (EmailAverage * Email); 
    break;
```

Comment: Could you give us some code to work with?

Comment: at least give us what did you try to help you, also controlling your filed is really simple, you just need to test if the content of each field different than  empty or null

Comment: Please add some code and show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: No code. The question is too general.

Comment: Validate your user inputs, theres no generic way to do that, it depends on the type of application etc. (answers for console apps are different to web apps)

Comment: Remove everything to do with the switch, if your programs flow dictates both are needed then make it do both

Answer (score 0):

Remove your switch statement and have your program do the following before the second case:

```
while(name.Length == 0) 
{
    Console.Write("Name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    if(name.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be empty");
    }
}
```